# Obter pasta da solução C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Tenho uma solução com 4 projetos dentro.
No meu controller preciso abrir um HTML que fica dentro de outro projeto, porém não consigo abrir a pasta do arquivo.

Abaixo segue print com minha estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo da classe é o Utils.cs o controller fica dentro de 1 - Services/JWT/Controllers
Tentei realizar a abertura do arquivo utilizando o seguinte código...

```
Criei uma classe no projeto onde está meu arquivo HTML.

public static class UtilDirectory
{

    public static string GetDirectory()
    {
        return Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }

}
```

No controller onde faço a instância da classe acesso da seguinte forma:

```
var directory = UtilDirectory.GetDirectory();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(directory + @"/ApiUtils/HtmlEmail/CorpoEmailBoletoDimensao.html");

string mensagem = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

Porém quando eu faço ao fazer desta forma acabo obtendo a pasta do meu projeto que está o controller e não o do Html propriamente dito.

Podem me ajudar por gentileza?

Comment: Creio que esse pequeno tutorial irá lhe ajudar. 
https://www.dotnetperls.com/directory-getfiles

Comment: Qual caminho está vindo no `directory `? se você chama o método `GetDirectory()` de dentro de um `controller`, ele vai retornar o diretório do `controller`

Comment: Devido a restrições de segurança, não é muito recomendado acessar arquivos fora do escopo do diretório de um projeto web. Já que este arquivo é de outro projeto, poderia fazer uma API que retorne ele, ao invés de buscar no Arquivo.

Comment: @Barbetta Exatamente, ele me retorna o caminho do controller, e por conta disso não consigo abrir o arquivo Html.

Comment: @Tony vou tentar fazer desta forma.

Comment: Se der certo, você me conta que coloco aquele comentário meu como resposta, OK?

Comment: O correto seria a pasta HtmlEmail estar na estrutura da aplicação Web ou em qualquer lugar que você quiser deixar no servidor, porém configurando o seu caminho no appsettings.json e garantindo que o usuário que roda a aplicação tenha permissão de acesso ao path e arquivos.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo consegue me dar um exemplo de como configuraria o caminho no appsettings.json ? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionei o problema adicionando uma pasta de dados para a solution.

```
string baseDir = env.ContentRootPath;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDir, "App_Data"));
```

E recuperando a pasta no meu controller para acesso ao arquivo da seguinte forma.

```
      string dataDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();

      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataDir + @"/CorpoEmailBoletoDimensao.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Muito complicado manter isso dessa forma.
Adicione o arquivo da class library `ApiUtils` como uma referência no projeto Web. Assim você poderá usar da seguinte forma:

> StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(directory +
>   @"/CorpoEmailBoletoDimensao.html")

Veja os passo 1, 2 e 3 no link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963750/add-file-as-a-link-on-visual-studio-debug-vs-publish

Comment: Obrigado Roberto. Eu consegui fazer de outra forma. Acabei esquecendo do tópico. Vou publicar a resposta como solução.